# How to get information about user in head markup of community

Tags: community, javascript-remoting, experience-builder-page, ajax-toolkit

Experience Builder--> Settings-->Advance-->Head Markup
I tested already things like

```
<script src="../../soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js"></script>
<script>
    var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
</script>
```

but I got the errors :

```
   POST https://{site}.my.site.com/services/Soap/u/33.0 500 (Server Error) AND Session Id
```

Is any other way to get info about user in js ? Remote actions ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve it from that section of the builder. It's been our experience that access to the data layer with javascript from the Head Markup area in the builder doesn't really work.

If you can access the actual template with the head element directly it might be worth trying to add it there and see if that succeeds. Could also be that you need to load your code from a custom lightning component or aura page or something that gets it outside the builder environment.

Fwiw there are some expressions you can use in the builder to get user info but it's not much and I suspect doesn't fit your requirements:

- [Use Expressions to Add Dynamic Data to Aura Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_expressions_aura.htm)